# Formula recalculation in excel template POI JAVA

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel template file with formulas in some cells, I open it and fill in the values using POI. The problem is that the formulas aren't automatically recalculated. But if I open this file and click on a cell with a value, it recalculates that cell.

I found two ways to solve this issue in the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#:%7E:text=Recalculation%20of%20Formulas), but neither helped me.

The point is that Excel caches previously calculated results and you need to trigger recalculation to updated them.

1. Re-evaluate formulas with POI's FormulaEvaluator

   `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();`
2. Delegate re-calculation to Excel. The application will perform a full recalculation when the workbook is opened

   `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`

My code:

```
    public static String fillBook(String filename, String outFilename,  int sheetNumber, String[] params){ 
        String result = "";
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);

            Workbook workbook = null;
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);

            for (String param: params)
            {
                String[] paramArray = param.split("\u0001");
                String address = paramArray[0];
                String value;

                if (paramArray.length > 1)
                {
                    value = paramArray[1];
                } else {
                    value = "";
                }

                CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(address);
                Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());

                if (row == null) {
                    row = sheet.createRow(cellReference.getRow());
                }

                Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol(), Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                cell.setCellValue(value);
            }

            //workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
            workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();

            result = e.toString() + " " + exceptionAsString;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly means "but neither helped me"? Both methods work as told in documentation. So where and how exactly are you trying to get the calculated values and how does it fail?

Comment: @AxelRichter I updated the question with my code

Comment: The question was where and how exactly are you trying to get the calculated values and how does it fail? The `setForceFormulaRecalculation` only works using `Excel`. It does not work using `OpenOffice` or `LibreOffice` `Calc`. But  `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll` should evaluate all formulas in workbook or should throw exception. And it should store the results as cached formula cell values. If not, what `apache poi` version? What formula gets not evaluated?

Comment: @AxelRichter I use Microsoft Excel template. My POI version is 3.17. I use simple formulas, like `SUM(A1:A10)`. But I use formulas in Russian( `СУММ(А1:А10)` ), maybe that's the problem? But in any case, `setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)` should work, right?

Comment: Yes `setForceFormulaRecalculation` should work when the result file gets opened using `Excel`. Except you disabled auto calculation in `Excel`. And the formula localization is not the problem as `Excel` stores formulas in `en-US` always. The localization is done in local `Excel` application only. But what errors you get using `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll()`?

Comment: *Argh*. I've overseen something in your code. All new values you set are string values. So if `String[] paramArray` contains "123" for example, you set the string "123" as cell value instead of the number 123. But `SUM` cannot sum strings. It only sums numeric values. So it only will work if you change cell having "123" in it to have 123 then. So set numeric values as numeric values. There are methods in `Cell` for this. [void setCellValue(double value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-double-) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set all cell values as string values in Excel. Formulas which expect numeric values or date values will not work when the referred cells contain string values.

As of your provided code, all new values you set are string values. So if `String[] paramArray` contains "123" for example, you set the string "123" as cell value instead of the number 123. But for example formula `SUM`  cannot sum strings. It only sums numeric values. So it only will work if you change cell having "123" in it to have 123 then. So set numeric values as numeric values. There are methods in `Cell` for this. [void setCellValue(double value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-double-) for example.

The same is with date values. Those also needs to be set as date values into the cells instead simply as strings.

So you need a different object than `String[] params` to hand over the cell values. This object must be able to store numeric values too. For example a `List<Object>` or a `List<POJO>` where `POJO` is any kind of plain old Java object storing the information. Then use different `setCellValue` methods of [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) to set string cell values or numeric cell values or date cell values.

Else you need creating a numeric value (`double`) from the string got from `String[] params` before you set it into the `Cell`. Same for date values - create a date value (`Calendar` or `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`) from the string got from `String[] params` before you set it into the `Cell`. But that is the more error prone approach in my opinion.

Comment: Can you help me on this .. facing similar issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716993/apache-poi-conditional-formatting-highlight-issue-using-java